# ¿Por qué no me funciona la verificación de la contraseña en html y JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy empezando con esto de HTML y JavaScript, y practicando se me ocurrió hacer una página para loguearme con usuario y contraseña. Cuando ingreso el usuario, funciona perfecto: lee el usuario que se escribe y lo guarda en una variable, luego lo compara con el nombre de usuario guardado en otra variable y si coinciden, se sigue al paso de colocar la contraseña. Pero cuando escribo la contraseña, NO lee la contraseña que el usuario escribe y no la guarda en la variable. Entonces el programa falla.
Adjunto el código HTML y JS:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">            
            
            <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>

            <script src="loginDeUsuarioRefactor.js"></script>            

        </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="titulo">Prueba de login</h1>

        <section id="login">
            <h2 id="iniciar-sesion">Iniciar sesión</h2>
        </section>

        <section id="nombre-de-usuario">
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="usuario" placeholder="e-mail o nombre de usuario"/>
            
            <p>______________________________</p>
            
            <p>¿No tenés cuenta? 
                <a href="file:///D:/Documentos/Proyectos%20Web/Mis%20proyectos%20web/Register%20y%20Login/registrarse.html">Creá una cuenta acá</a> </p>            
        </section>

        <section id="contraseña">
            <h2 id="escribir-contraseña">Escribir contraseña</h2>   
            
            <input type="password" name="userPassword" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
        </section>        

        <section id="boton-siguiente">
            <button id="siguiente">Siguiente</button>
        </section>

        <br>

        <section id="boton-iniciar-sesion">
            <button id="iniciar-sesion">Iniciar sesión</button>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
let usuario 
let contraseña 
let usuarioRegistrado = "usuariodeprueba@hotmail.com"
let contraseñaRegistrada ="probando1234"



//Primero lee todo el HTML y luego ejecuta la función iniciarTesteo
window.addEventListener("load", iniciar)

function iniciar() {
    //Ocultar texto que dice "Escribir contraseña"
    let sectionPass = document.getElementById("contraseña")
    sectionPass.style.display = "none"
    
    //Ocultar botón "iniciar Sesión" que aparece al escribir la contraseña
    let sectionIniciarSesion = document.getElementById("boton-iniciar-sesion")
    sectionIniciarSesion.style.display = "none"
    
    let botonSiguiente = document.getElementById("siguiente")
    botonSiguiente.addEventListener("click", chequearUsuarioYContraseña)
}

function chequearUsuarioYContraseña() {   
    chequearUsuario()  
    let botonIniciarSesion = document.getElementById("iniciar-sesion")  
    botonIniciarSesion.addEventListener("click", verificarPassword) 
}

function chequearUsuario() {
    usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value
    
    let sectionLogin = document.getElementById("login") 
    let sectionNombreDeUsuario = document.getElementById("nombre-de-usuario")   
    let sectionPass = document.getElementById("contraseña")
    let sectionBotonSiguiente = document.getElementById("boton-siguiente")
    let sectionIniciarSesion = document.getElementById("boton-iniciar-sesion")
    
    if(usuario === usuarioRegistrado) {        
        sectionLogin.style.display = "none"
        sectionNombreDeUsuario.style.display = "none"
        sectionBotonSiguiente.style.display = "none"
        sectionPass.style.display = "block"
        sectionIniciarSesion.style.display = "block"  
    }
    else {
        alert("El nombre de usuario no existe")
    }
}

function verificarPassword() {
    verificacion()
}

function verificacion() {
    contraseña = document.getElementById("password").value 

    if(contraseña === contraseñaRegistrada) {
        window.open("file:///D:/Documentos/Proyectos%20Web/Mis%20proyectos%20web/Register%20y%20Login%20-%20refactor/registrarse-refactor.html")
    }
    else {
        alert("Contraseña incorrecta!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El único problema que existe en tu código es que tienes un ID duplicado, los ID son para identificar elementos únicos, si quieres seleccionar elementos con la misma palabra, deberías usar clases y no ID's. Al escribir en tu Script:

```
let botonIniciarSesion = document.getElementById("iniciar-sesion")
```

Estas llamando al elemento que tenga ese ID, pero tú tienes 2 elementos con el mismo ID por lo que seleccionara el primero que se encuentre en el documento. Tienes este `<h2>`:

```
  <section id="login">
      <h2 id="iniciar-sesion">Iniciar sesión</h2>
  </section>
```

Y despues el verdadero boton:

```
  <section id="boton-iniciar-sesion">
      <button id="iniciar-sesion">Iniciar sesión</button>
  </section>
```

Solo tienes que eliminar el `id='iniciar-sesion'` del `<h2>` o cambiarlo por otro que no exista ya en el documento y listo, ya funciona perfecto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por responder y por darme la solución. Increíble que haya sido tan descuidado de poner un "id" duplicado.